# API Gateway integration with backend cluster in another account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have an API Gateway in Account A and I want to integrate with an ECS cluster backend in Account B. There is an ALB in Account B. Both accounts use Transit Gateway to communicate to each other. Communications must be private.

How can I achieve this?
Is there a way that I can expose a NLB in account B to point my VPC-Link to?

Edit:

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11hP8.jpg)

Comment: What do you want to achive, exactly? Do you want the ECS Service to call an API? or vica versa, the API would call the ECS Service? or the API would expose the ECS Service as an endpoint? Please be more accurate with your question!!

Comment: The API Gateway has to call the cluster